# Creating hash with Ruby class

Tags: ruby

I am barely a week into learning Ruby and do not understand what I am doing correctly in this code.

```
 class Address
  attr_accessor :type, :street, :city, :state
  def initialize (type, street, city, state)
    @type = type
    @street = street
    @city = city
    @state = state
  end
  def show
    puts "Address.show: #{type}"
    puts "#{self.street} \n #{self.city}, #{}self.state}"
  end
end

class Person
  attr_accessor :first, :last, :address_list
  def initialize (first, last)
    @first = first
    @last = last
    @address_list = Address.hash {}
  end

  def show
    puts "From Person.show"
    puts "#{self.first} #{self.last}"

    #puts @addresses.keys
  end

  def address(addr)
    @key = addr.type
    @address_list[@key] = addr    # FAILS HERE 
    puts @address_list.keys
    puts @address_list[@key]
  end
end

# Test
puts "Creating Person"
person=Person.new("Bob","Jones")
person.first="Robert"
person.show

puts "Creating Addresses"
addr1 = Address.new("home", "3103 Hayward St", "Bellingham,","WA")
addr2 = Address.new("work", "123 Main Street", "Hillsdale,","OR")

puts "Adding addresses to person"
person.address(addr1)
person.address(addr2)

puts "Showing Addresses"
addr1.show
addr2.show

puts "Showing Person"
person.show
```

I have made he changes recommended by @Arun, but I still get this message:
F:/MyDocs/ruby/Contacts//person.rb:32:in `address': undefined method` []=' for 1049615506:Integer (NoMethodError)

Comment: The first right brace in `#{}self.state}"`, in `show`, is probably not wanted, but it is treated as an ordinary character so it doesn't raise an exception.

Comment: @CarySwoveland actually it’s the first right brace that needs deletion.

Comment: @matt, that's what I said (eventually).

Comment: @CarySwoveland I know what you mean

Comment: @Bob Jones Replace `@address_list = Address.hash {}` with `@address_list = {}` as suggested in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

`Address.hash` returns an integer hash value of the object (in this case, the class `Address`). You should set `@address_List` to an empty hash.

```rb
@address_List = {}
```

And

```
puts @addresses[key]
```

should be

```
puts @address_List[@key]
```

---

It's a convention in Ruby to use `snake_case` for variable names. So, `address_List` would be `address_list`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are running into is caused by the assignment to `address_list`
Address.hash returns an integer.  See [this](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Object.html#:%7E:text=Object%20is%20the%20default%20root,in%20kernel%20functions%20globally%20accessible.) page for details.
What you probably wanted is `@address_list = {}`

```
  def initialize (first, last)
    @first = first
    @last = last
    @address_list = Address.hash {}  # this calls the hash method on Address which returns an integer
  end
```

This is pretty much what Arun says in his answer but maybe you missed the first part? Here is the updated code which runs fine for me.

```
class Address
  attr_accessor :type, :street, :city, :state
  def initialize (type, street, city, state)
    @type = type
    @street = street
    @city = city
    @state = state
  end
  def show
    puts "Address.show: #{type}"
    # puts "#{self.street} \n #{self.city}, #{}self.state}"
    puts "#{self.street} \n #{self.city}, #{self.state}"
  end
end

class Person
  attr_accessor :first, :last, :address_list
  def initialize (first, last)
    @first = first
    @last = last
    # @address_list = Address.hash {}
    @address_list =  {}
  end

  def show
    puts "From Person.show"
    puts "#{self.first} #{self.last}"

    #puts @addresses.keys
  end

  def address(addr)
    @key = addr.type
    @address_list[@key] = addr    # FAILS HERE 
    puts @address_list.keys
    puts @address_list[@key]
  end
end

# Test
puts "Creating Person"
person=Person.new("Bob","Jones")
person.first="Robert"
person.show

puts "Creating Addresses"
addr1 = Address.new("home", "3103 Hayward St", "Bellingham,","WA")
addr2 = Address.new("work", "123 Main Street", "Hillsdale,","OR")

puts "Adding addresses to person"
person.address(addr1)
person.address(addr2)

puts "Showing Addresses"
addr1.show
addr2.show

puts "Showing Person"
person.show
```